# How to make div elements display inline

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage for my game development group, and on the page I have some content pods which I'll be using to showcase our projects. The pods are div elements and their container is another div element. I have it like this so that the elements can scroll if they end up going off the end of the page. However, I am having trouble making this work. The elements aren't displaying inline. Whenever I do try to make the elements display inline they all dissapear...

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content-box1"></div>
    <div id="content-box2"></div>
    <div id="content-box3"></div>
    <div id="content-box4"></div>
    <div id="content-box5"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS For the elements.

```
#content-wrapper{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 190px;
height: 140px;
overflow: scroll;
width: 90%;

}
#content-box1, #content-box2, #content-box3, #content-box4, #content-box5 {
position:relative;
height:120px;
color:#a8d540;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size:20pt;
background-color:#a8d540;
border:none;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content-box1 {
width:200px;
background-image:url('img/trenches.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
#content-box2 {
width:200px;
background-image:url('img/textcity.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
#content-box3{
width:200px;
background-image:url('img/consoleclash.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
#content-box4{
width:200px;
background-image:url('img/contrarycollision.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
#content-box5{
width:200px;
background-image:url('img/consoleclash.png'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: You should assign a class to the content boxes so you can share CSS better. Then use the id to distinguish them.

Comment: `display: inline;` will work as soon as you put some content in your divs. It's not working now because you don't have any content.

Comment: @TylerH That is not the case, as I had thought that at first, but adding text to it just made the text display inline, not the background of the element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qZN5v/

change display:inline to float:left

```
 #content-box1, #content-box2, #content-box3, #content-box4, #content-box5 {
 position:relative;
 height:120px;
 color:#a8d540;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size:20pt;
 background-color:#a8d540;
 border:none;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
```

}

Comment: Thank you, perhaps you could help me with another thing? I have it set to make the x overflow scroll, and the Y overflow hide, But it seems that anything that overflows goes down beneath the visible elements, Any Ideas?

Comment: you must change #content-wrapper height

sample = height: 180px;

Comment: That isn't what i'm trying at, I'm trying to make the elements that overflow scroll on the x-axis, your proposed solution simply extends the region into which the overflowing elements are visible.

Answer (score 1):

It need to be `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:inline;`

```
#content-box1, #content-box2, #content-box3, #content-box4, #content-box5 {
position:relative;
height:120px;
color:#a8d540;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size:20pt;
background-color:#a8d540;
border:none;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block; 
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/teray/1)**